# Trying to disable all notifications except for one on woocommerce checkout page with css

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, css, html, notifications

Below is the structure of the html, I am trying to `display: none` all but one of the notifications that appear when a user doesn't fill in the required fields on a `woocommerce` checkout page (the children of `woocommerce-NoticeGroup woocommerce-NoticeGroup-checkout`).

```
<div class="woocommerce-NoticeGroup woocommerce-NoticeGroup-checkout">
<!---->
    <div class="woocommerce-error alert alert_error" role="alert">
        <div class="alert_wrapper">Please fill in the required information</div>
        <a class="close" href="#"><i class="icon-cancel"></i></a>
    </div>
<!---->
    <div class="woocommerce-error alert alert_error" role="alert">
        <div class="alert_wrapper">Please fill in the required information</div>
        <a class="close" href="#"><i class="icon-cancel"></i></a>
    </div>
<!---->
    <div class="woocommerce-error alert alert_error" role="alert">
        <div class="alert_wrapper">Please fill in the required information</div>
        <a class="close" href="#"><i class="icon-cancel"></i></a>
    </div>
<!---->
</div>
```

I have tried `:not(:first-child)`, `:not(:first-of-type)`, `:nth-child(n+1)` and some others. Something that might help with the problem is that when I do `nth-child(1)` all of the notifications disappear instead of the first one just disappearing, and then `nth-child(2)` brings all the notifications back...instead of just removing the second child. So it seems all the notifications are combined in one child somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the css selector I used doesn't match the HTML structure, this worked for only allowing one notification through when more than one field is not filled out on the checkout page of a woocommerce site:

```
#Content > div > div > div > div.section.mcb-section > div > div > div > div > div > div > form.checkout.woocommerce-checkout > div.woocommerce-NoticeGroup.woocommerce-NoticeGroup-checkout:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(n+2) {
  display: none;
}
```

Not sure why `> div:nth-child(n+2)`, all I should need is the first `nth-child` to be `nth-child(n+1)`